# Update variables in java class from gradle.properties

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I'm converting a project from maven to gradle and want to be able to continue passing arguments via command line

> eg. mvn clean test -Dwebsite=abc >>> gradle test -Pwebsite=abc

In my current mvn project I have multiple properties file which can be updated from a class file called `environment.java` (ie. the properties file can change depending on the parameter I pass in so instead of `abc` I can pass in `xyz` which loads a different properties file).

With gradle I know I need a gradle.properties file with the property defined. I'm trying to get the gradle.properties file to update `environment.java` which then updates java properties file.

I've tried to load the properties in the build.gradle and the main class but have had no luck.  I think what I'm looking for is some sort of mapping between `gradle.properties` to `environment.java` if its even possible.

Comment: If you have some value inside of the your gradle.properties file like mykey=myval then write ${mykey} in the your build.gradle file (to grab property from gradle.properties file )and add it into java class.

Comment: Ok I understand the first part but how would I reference ${mykey} in the java class?